# loading a docker container of geomesa accumulo in openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I was trying almost all built containers in the internet of Geomesa Accumulo to be used as a container in Openshift.
an example of a docker container is this one 
https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geodocker-geomesa/geodocker-geomesa-local.html

What I do in fact is to modify the dockerfile so I can run it in openshift, by adding non root user, and changing the ownership of the files to him.
However It does not work.

Any suggestions regarding that?

Comment: And the errors/problem was? What was the original `Dockerfile`? What did you change the `Dockerfile` to? Adding a non root user is not always enough. File system permissions also need to change. Even then, applications may want to grab privileged ports meaning there is no way to run as non root.

Comment: Hi @pochi . Your question isn't specific enough to yield useful responses. You can try to improve your question by explaining what you tried, and what error messages you saw. StackOverflow works best when you ask specific questions, which have specific answers, rather than asking for general suggestions.

Also, please don't overuse tags. Some of your tags only marginally relate to your question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280173/should-tags-primarily-be-used-for-categorization-or-searchability/280210